# Can an argument ever be of the wrong type in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

In JavaScript:

```
function doSomething(mybar) {
  if (!(mybar instanceof Bar)) throw new TypeError("mybar");
  // ...other guard clauses
}
```

In TypeScript:

```
function doSomething(mybar: Bar) {
  // is guard clause ALWAYS redundant?
  // ...other guard clauses
}
```

I like to validate inputs with guard clauses. So in JavaScript I'd test that `mybar` is an instance of `Bar`, and if it isn't then I'd throw a `TypeError`.

In TypeScript is `mybar` guaranteed to be the correct type? (And thus eliminate the need for that first guard clause)

---

UPDATE

There are a few good answers below, which range from "it's definitely possible" to "it could happen" to "it can't happen".

So maybe a good way to phrase the question is - if it's possible that the wrong type is supplied at runtime, what is the mechanism by which that would happen? A bug in typecasting for example?

Comment: Yes and no. You can't guarantee the afterlife of your code. The linter/hinter and the transpiler will check your type, but there is nothing at runtime that will do the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`instanceof` is a test if the object is an instance of `Bar`. While this means the type of the parameter is also `Bar` the reverse is not necessarily true. Typescript uses structural typing, so any object with the structure of `Bar` will be compatible with the function parameter. So this this code is perfectly valid:

```
class Bar {
    bar: number;
}
function doSomething(p: Bar) { }
doSomething({
    bar: 10
})
```

When you have private properties, you can't 'fake' the object so easily, but even then, we can always assert to `any`:

```
class Bar {
    private bar: number;
}
function doSomething(p: Bar) { }
doSomething({ // error now
    bar: 10
})
doSomething({ // breaking out of type safety
    bar: 10
} as any)
```

And if your code-base is not entirely TS, then any type safety goes out the window, JS can call your TS function with whatever it pleases.

Does this mean you should always include the check ? I would argue against it. JS is pretty loose with its types (and so is TS), and this is what your users expect. If it quacks like a duck it is a duck,  the old JS mantra goes. If the object has the properties to work with your function it should work with your function regardless of how it was created.

Comment: As a javascript developer I experienced the same issue however let's consider this case we are parsing json and/or getting records (let's say bar returns string somehow) from db and passing to this function there is no way typescript will throw an error in runtime if we don't have type check against the function parameter. while writing unit test for the similar case ts compiler yelled at me in test file that I am passing an invalid argument, which I did intentionally to throw an error. What is the "typescript" way of handling this issue ? And yes  "as any" rescued but I kinda feel it's hacky.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your updated question:

> If it's possible that the wrong type is supplied at runtime, what is
>   the mechanism by which that would happen? A bug in typecasting for
>   example?

There are a few ways it could happen:

- `doSomething` was called from a JavaScript file (without `checkJs` or `@ts-check`)
- An object similar to `Bar` is supplied. It's the same structurally, but it's not an instance of `Bar`.
- An argument of incorrect type was cast to `Bar` by another developer
- An argument of incorrect type was automatically cast to `any` (missing type definitions, type inference getting lost)
- An argument of incorrect type was asserted to be `Bar` by a poorly written type guard
- An argument of incorrect type was treated as `Bar` because its definition was augmented somewhere else in your project
- Your code was shipped and consumed in an environment where there is no build pipeline, and therefore no compile-time errors can exist (e.g. distributed as a UMD package)
- An object or array was index using a non-existing key (TypeScript assumes it can never be `undefined`)
- A questionably typed part of the standard library is used in the mix (for example, `Promise.resolve.call(1)` will throw in runtime even though TypeScript accepts that)

Comment: I didn't realize there were so many scenarios...very thorough, and appreciated, thanks! I'm gonna carry on using a guard clause just to be safe.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your function. If it is a private function, only you have access to it then TS can help ensure if it compiles, it's always the correct type. If it's a public function, that is supposed to be used by another user/party, then a check is necessary if you want to have some resilience.

TS type is about designing your software, doesn't matter how good you design it if the user chooses to hold it in the wrong way, it breaks. So expose only few public places only and put checks there.

Comment: Good advice. However, if that public code was written by me too, and went through ts transpiler too, then how can the wrong type ever be provided? What is the mechanism by which such a thing can occur?

Comment: Then you don't need redundant checks, and you just need to learn to trust TS, like a function you write.

Comment: Your answer is good and appreciates, but the accepted answer explains in depth the underlying technical details.

Comment: If I must be honest, I feel that answer is off topic. But there are nuances that I don't know so I could be wrong. Glad you found many things helpful via this Q

Answer (score 1):

Things work differently in TypeScript than JavaScript, with TypeScript if you pass argument of any other type than what is specified in function signature, you'll get error during compilation and thus you are bound to follow the exact type of function arguments.

Comment: But as @ZorgoZ explained above, at runtime the code can still misbehave? Or can that never happen?

Comment: @Ionix I myself have been using TS for more than 4 years now, have never ran into any situation where code misbehaved even after specifying arguments type in function definition. :)

Comment: That sounds like advice from an expert, so I thank you! :-)